# How do I use python loops to iterate through the same code with different arguments?

Tags: python, pandas, loops

Moving from SAS to Python, I am trying to replicate a SAS macro-type process using input parameters to generate different iterations of code for each loop. In particular, I am trying to binarize continuous variables for modeling (regardless of the merit that may have). What I'm doing at the moment looks as follows:

Some sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
data=[[2,20],[4,50],[6,75],[1,80],[3,40]]
df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['var1','var2'])
```

Then I run the following:

```
df['var1_f'] = pd.cut(df['var1'], [0,1,2,3,4,5,7,np.inf], include_lowest=True, labels=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'])
df['var2_f'] = pd.cut(df['var2'], [-np.inf,0,62,73,81,98,np.inf], include_lowest=True, labels=['a','b','c','d','e','f'])
.
.
.

df1=pd.get_dummies(df,columns=['var1_f'])
df1=pd.get_dummies(df1,columns=['var2_f'])
.
.
.
```

The above results in a table that contains the original DataFrame, but now has columns appended that take values 1 or 0, depending on whether the continuous variable falls into a particular band. That's great. There must be a better way to do this, rather than having potentially a dozen or so entries that are structurally identical, just with different arguments for variable names and cutoff/label values?

The SAS equivalent would involve replacing "varx_f", "varx", the cutoff values and the labels with placeholders that change on each iteration. In this case, I would do that through pre-defined values (as per the values in the above code), rather than dynamically.

How would I go about looping through this with different arguments for each iteration?

Apologies if this is an existing topic (I'm sure it is) - I just haven't been able to find it.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204560/discussion-on-question-by-akswift-how-do-i-use-python-loops-to-iterate-through-t).

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't allowed to move to chat... @SamuelLiew